# Need help editing a JavaScript file for a responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone help me edit the following script? The responsive menu is working, but I'd like to get the mobile version of the menu to collapse when "link1" or "link2" is clicked.

========================================================
This is the script:

```
    $(function() {
    var pull        = $('#pull');
        menu        = $('#nav-bar ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

========================================================
Navbar HTML:

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="clearfix">
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="#link1">LINK1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">LINK2</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="pull">MENU</a>
</div>
```

========================================================
    CSS:

```
     /* Clearfix */
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
*zoom: 1;
}

#nav-bar {
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav-bar ul {
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
}

#nav-bar li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

#nav-bar a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 65px;
}


#nav-bar a:hover,
#nav-bar a:active,
.active {
    background-color: #343434;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px #2d2d2d inset;
}

#nav-bar a#pull {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: "Pull" is unnecessarily wrapped in the jQuery object twice. Also, is there a reason menu and menuHeight are global variables? This will fail in strict mode as it may cause unexpected behavior. Is there a reason you aren't having media queries handle this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the media queries. I think the menu is styled correctly though, resizing for different size screens etc. The mobile menu expands when clicked, but doesn't collapse when a link is clicked. Can you help edit the script? I couldn't get the suggestion below to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#nav-bar ul li a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();   
    menu.slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Not sure where this goes, tried a number of different ways but couldn't get it to work.